# Having some troubles understanding this code

Tags: generative-adversarial-network

[The image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdsp9.png)

What does the 5 highlighted lines of the code mean?

Basically to get the "get_top_covariances", I need to follow these 4 steps.

1. Start by finding the covariance matrix
2. The target feature should not be included in the outputs.
3. It may be easiest to solve this if you find the relevant_indices first, and then use relevant_indices to calculate highest_covariances.
4. You want to sort by absolute value but return the actual values.

Hence, I would highlight appreciate it if anyone could help to explain those 5 lines,as in what's it is trying to do.

By the way, what's that top_n for? I'm quite lost at this part.

Comment: Please don't post screenshot of code. And read the the guidelines for posting questions here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'll take note of that, but can someone explain to me what does the 5 lines of code means? I'm completely lost.